# ExtJS 4.2 remove row from grid not calling API php code

Tags: jquery, extjs

I've got a button which, when clicked will remove a selected row from the grid.
The problem is for some reason the php back-end code isn't getting called.

The commented out line g.getStore().remove(v2) clears the row in the grid but I need to get the php declared in the API to execute. The php isn't being called so I am wondering what I have missed.

Button click code:

```
var g = Ext.getCmp("acc_grid");
var vals = g.getSelectionModel(); 
if (vals.hasSelection()) {
   var v2 = vals.getSelection();
   //g.getStore().remove(v2);//clears the row from grid - no probs
   // really I would like to remove the row from the backend php so 

    g.getStore().remove({  // the bit which is not working.......
       params: {sid: current_session,
                 id :v2[0].get('clid')
               }});
    g.getStore().reload();
}
```

Store defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('ROMLProjectAdmin.store.AcSt', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'ROMLProjectAdmin.model.AccModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'ROMLProjectAdmin.model.AccModel',
        storeId: 'AcSt',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            api: {
                create: 'http://localhost:8888/dm/newaccount.php',
                read: 'http://localhost:8888/dm/accl.php',
                update: 'http://localhost:8888/dm/cliupd.php',
                destroy: 'http://localhost:8888/dm/clirm.php'
            },
            url: '',
            callbackKey: 'callback1',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'clientname'
            },
            {
                name: 'clientemail'
            },
            {
                name: 'clid'
            },
            {
                name: 'crid'
            },
            {
                name: 'cltel'
            },
            {
                name: 'sinc'
            }
        ]
    }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

Thanks in advance for any clues here.

Kevin

Comment: Read the docs for remove. You need to pass it a model instance.

Comment: Where is the unique id? I mean, `idProperty`. You should catch this id from server side then do what you want.